# Polynomials cubic equation

Tags: polynomials

Cubic equations can contain a max of 3 solutions.

y=2x^3+3

From this equation is there anyway to factorise this and getting three solutions instead of one. What makes this equation only have one solution if getting three solutions is impossible?

Comment: Hint:  $\frac32=\left(\sqrt[3]\frac32\right)^3$.

Comment: $2x^3+3=0$ has one real solution and two nonreal complex solutions, making three solutions all told.

Comment: Any thoughts, Dixon?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has lost interest.